# BERTopic / umap crashing with cosine metric

Tags: python, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity, topic-modeling

I'm using python bertopic library for topic modeling of Polish tweets in a straightforward way, i.e.,

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from bertopic import BERTopic

model = SentenceTransformer("sdadas/st-polish-paraphrase-from-distilroberta")
topic_model = BERTopic(embedding_model = model)
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)
```

where `docs` is a set of over 800k tweets.

The problem I encounter is that in case I restrict myself to 100k documents there are no problems, however, if I exceed this number I end up with a segmentation fault.

I have dug a little bit and figured out that probably the main cause of the problem is the `umap` package that provides the dimensionality reduction algorithm, i.e., if I first obtain the embeddings with `model.encode()` function and perform

```
umap_embeddings = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=15, n_components=5,metric='cosine').fit_transform(embeddings)
```

I end up with the same result of seg fault. However, if I switch the `metric` to `euclidean`, then it all works fine with the full set of 800k documents. To be funnier, cosine metric sometimes works with 300k, 500k or even 600k documents but not always (umap is not deterministic).

I understand that the main reason could be memory issues, however, I get similar results when tested on 64GB RAM standalone PC and 378GB RAM Epyc server, even with `memory_low=True` option.

Comment: Are you using a GPU or a CPU?

Comment: I'm using a CPU.

Comment: Maybe switching to a GPU-based approach could resolve your issue. Please see the corresponding BERTopic documentation : https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/dim_reduction/dim_reduction.html#cuml-umap

Answer (score 0):

I managed to help it a little by implementing cosinus function directly in the notebook - yet on a very large dataset it didn't go through even on my 1.5TB RAM AI-LAB computer.

```html
@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def my_cosinus(x, y):
    result = 0.0
    norm_x = 0.0
    norm_y = 0.0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        result += x[i] * y[i]
        norm_x += x[i] ** 2
        norm_y += y[i] ** 2

    if norm_x == 0.0 and norm_y == 0.0:
        return 0.0
    elif norm_x == 0.0 or norm_y == 0.0:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 1.0 - (result / np.sqrt(norm_x * norm_y))


umap_embeddings = UMAP(n_neighbors=15,     
                        n_components=5, 
                        metric=my_cosinus,
                        low_memory=True,
                        verbose=False).fit_transform(embeddings)
```